# Facebook SDK 3.1: Unknown error during authorization process using pre-IOS6 emulator

Tags: facebook, ipad, permissions, authorization

I have a problem when authorizing an application for the first time using Facebook sdk 3.1 if i ran the application in iPad 4.3 simulator.

This is my code :

```
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos",nil] 
                 allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                          switch (state)
                 {
                     //case FBSessionStateCreated:
                     //case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:
                     case FBSessionStateOpen:

                          [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil]
                                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                            [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                state:session.state
                                                                error:error
                                                              success:success
                                                              failure:failure];
                                            }];

                         break;
                     default:
                         break;
                  }

         }];

}
```

The application will call the safari and ask user to login. Once the application has been added to the Facebook, it trying to open a new page on safari I think that would be the reauthorizeWithPublishPermission part. Before it loaded that page, I have got kick out from Safari to the home screen of the iPad. This code here works on IOS6 although I have another issue on IOS6 so I have posted as a separate question.

The error on the console is this:

> 2013-02-12 10:15:16.012 PG Facebook[911:16b03] error = The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)
>   2013-02-12 10:15:17.187 PG Facebook[911:16b03] FBConditionalLog: handleOpenURL should not be called once a session has closed
>   Facebook[911:16b03] error = The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)
>   wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

These are the three main error i have seen on the console.
Does anyone know what is wrong?